# Conversion of date to string resulting in "None" in the string but no error in python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

I am trying to create a email body that I will then be able to send, the code works and returns the values that I expect until:

```
email_text = "Please can you " + str(move_plates) + " and " + str(read_plates)
```

when I use: `print(email_text)`

I then get "Please can you None and None" but no error, can anyone advise on how to fix this?

I'm assuming its an issue when I convert the date to a string.

```
def move_Plates():
    if _days_[movePlates.weekday()] == "Saturday":
        return ("change day " + str(_days_[movePlates.weekday()]) + "New Date: " + str(movePlates + timedelta(days = 2)))
    elif _days_[movePlates.weekday()] == "Sunday":
        return ("change day " + str(_days_[movePlates.weekday()]) + "New Date: " + str(movePlates + timedelta(days = 1)))
    else: 
        return (" move plates on: " + str(_days_[movePlates.weekday()]) + " " + str(movePlates))
move_plates = print(move_Plates())
move_plates

def read_Plates():
    if _days_[readPlates.weekday()] == "Saturday":
        return ("change day " + str(_days_[readPlates.weekday()])+ "New Date: " + str(movePlates + timedelta(days = 2)))
    elif _days_[readPlates.weekday()] ==  "Sunday":
        return ("change day " + str(_days_[readPlates.weekday()])+ "New Date: " + str(movePlates + timedelta(days = 1)))
    else: 
        return (" read plates on: " + str(_days_[readPlates.weekday()]) + " " + str(readPlates))
read_plates = print(read_Plates())
read_plates

email_text = "Please can you " + str(move_plates) + " and " + str(read_plates)
print(email_text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign the result of your function to a variable, you should write:

```
move_plates = move_Plates()
```

not:

```
move_plates = print(move_Plates())
```

---

`print(...)` has the effect of printing text to your terminal (to stdout more precisely), but doesn't *return* anything.

If you write `foo = print([anything])`, `foo` will always be `None`.

Comment: So how would I print the result of my function, when I remove the print(move_Plates) I print <function move_Plates at 0x000002EA25A2B7E0> rather than the result

Comment: Keep the `()`. `foo = Foo()` (with the parentheses) will store *the result you get when executing Foo*, `foo = Foo` will store *the function itself* (and will not execute it).

Answer (score 2):

The function `print` returns `None`
change the following

```py
#move_plates = print(move_Plates())
...
#read_plates = print(read_Plates())
```

to this

```py
move_plates = move_Plates()
...
read_plates = read_Plates()
```

Comment: So how would I print the result of my function, when I remove the print(move_Plates) I print <function move_Plates at 0x000002EA25A2B7E0> rather than the result